# Checking if a string is single/double quote literal and escape ASCII characters from it

Tags: ruby, string

I have a method that takes a multi-line string separated by /n ASCII character. The argument can be either a single quote/double quote string literal.

For instance,

```
"This is/n a multiline/n string".lines => ["This is", "a multiline", "string"]
```

But

```
'This is/n a multiline/n string'.lines => ["This is/n a multiline/n string"]
```

I need to separate the string by the /n. The string may be passed as either single or double quotes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is "/n ASCII character"?

Comment: I need a single solution that works. 'This is/n a multiline/n string'.split('/n') will solve the purpose but it will fail for "This is/n a multiline/n string".split('/n').

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `split` with a regexp matching both (the line feed control character `"\n"` and the string `'\n'`) instead of `lines`:

```
"This is\n a multiline\n string".split(/\n|\\n/)
#=> ["This is", " a multiline", " string"]
'This is\n a multiline\n string'.split(/\n|\\n/)
#=> ["This is", " a multiline", " string"]
```

Comment: Just a simple question, how to differentiate between a single quoted string and a double quoted string, as they both belong to the same "String" class? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: That is not the question. Both are just Strings, they are not different from the class point of view. The difference is that `"\n"` is a control character but `'\n'` are the two characters `'\'` and `'n'`. You might want to ask how to find out if a string contains control characters? But that would still not solve your problem because in your example there could be a string containing both. Therefore just handle both cases.